# How to make a image smaller if array is larger then 2 with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm making a dashboard where you can see the sold product details and where you can print the label so you can package it and send the product to the customer. I have made this dashboard for if there is only 1 product sold but not if there are multiple product sold. So for example if product A and product B is bought by one customer it will just show the first one because there is no other div that can show the second image. Now i know that i have to put the div in a foreach loop so it shows every product but then the image is as big as the screen. Now I'm trying to make the image that's in the div smaller with each product that sold so it fits nicely on 1 screen without the need to scroll to see each product. So that's why i thought like "why don't I just do 400px divided by each product that's sold" but i couldn't figure out on how to do that. Could anyone help me out?

If you look in the else function you can see that I tried to set the image with the function's `.height()` and `.width` but it doesn't work. It keeps the CSS style.

```
if (productCount == 1) {
    console.log(returnedData.productList[0].image);
    $("#productImg").attr("src",`${returnedData.productList[0].image}`);
    $('#productTitle').empty();
    $('#productTitle').append(returnedData.productList[0].product);
    $('#eanCode').empty();
    $('#eanCode').append(returnedData.productList[0].eanCode);
    $('#soldAmount').empty();
    $('#soldAmount').append(returnedData.productList[0].number);
    $('#orderNmr').empty();
    $('#orderNmr').append(returnedData.id);
    $("#eanValue").val('')
} else {
    console.log(productCount)
    var size = 400/productCount;
    $('productImages').height(size).width(size)
}
```

i'm using a css class because otherwise it will only use the style on the first div>image

```
.productImg {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 200px !important;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

html

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Product Image -->
    <div class="col-md-auto ">
        <img id="productImages" src="images/Scholl.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid border border-1 rounded productImg">

    </div>
    <!-- Product Information -->
    <div id="productInfo" class="col">
        <div style="background-color: grey" class="border border-1">
            <h5 class="text-sm-start productTitle"></h5>
        </div>
        <div>
             <p class="text-sm-start" id="eanCode"></p>
             <p class="text-sm-start" id="soldAmount"><small class="text-muted">Verkocht:</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first thing: you are probably missing the `#` symbol in your `productImages` selection. Second thing: use CSS to your advantage for the sizing. css-grid and css-flexbox are your friends. Third thing: your html does not seem to be ready to have multiple images or products. For example you can't have multiple elements with the id `productInfo`. How do you intend to display multiple product infos? same with product images.

Comment: This is not a job for JS but for CSS. It's also weird you're overusing  fixed widths (px) in this era of responsive design...

Comment: @JeanotZubler yeah the missing `#` was the problem and indeed it only does it for one of the element `productInfo`, is it possible to change the class values in css? or is this something that is done with css-grid and css-flexbox?

Comment: Don't use `important`....

Comment: Protip: Your script is more performant and concise if you chain jQuery methods: `$('#orderNmr').empty().append( ... )`

Comment: Dynamically adding images and changing values needs to be done in JS. I don't know JQuery, here is some pseudo jquery code that could help you: `foreach (product in returnedData.productList) { $('#imageContainer').AddChild(new Img().attr('src', product.image)) }` . In CSS I would try something like `#imageContainer { display: grid; grid-auto-flow: column; }